# How to join 3 tables to a single table in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to join 3 tables to a single table. Here is the scenario.

Table 1: Has user_id, app_id

Table 2: Has user_id, gender

Table 3: Has app_id, app_name(PC, Mobile)

Table 4: Has user_id, user_city

Now I am looking to get a count of users by mobile male, mobile female, pc male, pc female grouped by cities.

Here is my SQL. However, I guess I am doing it wrong with the joins. Please correct me.

```
SELECT
    t4.user_city,
    sum(case when t2.gender = 'm' and t3.app_name = 'PC' then 1 else 0 end) pcmale,
    sum(case when t2.gender = 'f' and t3.app_name = 'PC' then 1 else 0 end) pcfemale,
    sum(case when t2.gender = 'm' and t3.app_name = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end) mobilemale,
    sum(case when t2.gender = 'm' and t3.app_name = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end) mobilefemale,
FROM
    table1 t1
    inner join
    table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    inner join
    table3 t3 on t1.app_id = t3.app_id
    inner join
    table4 t4 on t1.user_id = t4.user_id
GROUP BY 1
```

Can we join multiple tables to a single table in the way i have done in my query. Please help

Comment: It runs. I am just not sure if I am doing it correctly and getting the right results. Do you see any issues with the approach to join multiple tables to the t1 table?

Comment: Mobile female should check for f, you are checking for m and group should be on t4.user_city

Comment: So what results do you get?

Comment: @radar group is already on t4.user_city

Comment: The joins appear to be correct besides that, as Rob Paller mentioned already, some data may be missed due to the use of INNER JOIN. Consider shifting the logic to LEFT OUTER JOINs. Why do you think the joins are incorrect? If you are receiving some incorrect results then mentioning the exact issue will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your joins are correct as written.

If there is a value in T1 that is not present in T2, T3, or T4 it will be excluded from your results. This is because the `JOIN` you have written is an `INTERSECTION`. For example, if a row in T1 had a value for `app_id` = '99' and T2 did not have a corresponding value of '99' for `app_id` than it would not be returned in the SQL you have written.

In those situations if you would like to return the row in T1 containing 'u' you will need to write a 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' which returns all records from the `LEFT` table and matching records from the `RIGHT` table. For example, T1 having a value of '99' for app_id you would get a NULL value for `app_name` in T3.

This is an overly simplified example of the `JOIN` logic in a query but it hopefully it's helpful.